# Spline Normal Calculation

Tags: math, spline, splines, cubic-spline

I am having a issue calculating the normal of a spline to extrude a mesh from.

Check the Image : [image]
 As you can see, the normals in a certain area apear flipped, and I have no idea why.

Relevant Code :

```
public Vector3 GetNormal(float t)
    {
        var tangent = GetTangent(t);
        var point = GetPoint(t);
        var accel = GetAcceleration(t);
        // we need to lerp up base don the control points
        int i;
        if (t >= 1f)
        {
            t = 1f;
            i = _points.Length - 4;
        }
        else
        {
            t = Mathf.Clamp01(t) * CurveCount;
            i = (int)t;
            t -= i;
            i *= 3;
        }
        //var rotaSource = GetControlPointRotation(i);
        //var rotaDest = GetControlPointRotation(i + 2);
        //var lerp = Mathf.Lerp(rotaSource, rotaDest,t);      
        //var normalRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(lerp,tangent);

        var binormal = Vector3.Cross(tangent, accel).normalized;

        var normalOr = Vector3.Cross(tangent, binormal).normalized;


        Debug.DrawLine(point, point + accel * 5, Color.blue);
        Debug.DrawLine(point, point + binormal * 5,Color.black);
        Debug.DrawLine(point, point + normalOr * 5, Color.yellow);
        Debug.DrawLine(point, point + tangent * 5, Color.magenta);

        if (Vector3.Dot(tangent, accel) > 0)
            return Vector3.up;

        return normalOr;
        //return (normalRotation*up).normalized;

    }


 public Vector3 GetAcceleration(float t)
        {
            int i;
            if (t >= 1f)
            {
                t = 1f;
                i = _points.Length - 4;
            }
            else
            {
                t = Mathf.Clamp01(t) * CurveCount;
                i = (int)t;
                t -= i;
                i *= 3;
            }

            return Bezier.GetSecondDerivative(_points[i], _points[i + 1], _points[i + 2],
                _points[i + 3], t).normalized;

        }



public Vector3 GetTangent(float t)
        {
            int i;
            if (t >= 1f)
            {
                t = 1f;
                i = _points.Length - 4;
            }
            else
            {
                t = Mathf.Clamp01(t) * CurveCount;
                i = (int)t;
                t -= i;
                i *= 3;
            }
            return
                Bezier.GetFirstDerivative(_points[i], _points[i + 1], _points[i + 2],
                    _points[i + 3], t).normalized;
        }
```

The Bezier Curve methods here :

```
     public static Vector3 GetPoint(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float t)
            {
                t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
                float OneMinusT = 1f - t;
                return OneMinusT*OneMinusT*OneMinusT*p0 + 3f*OneMinusT*OneMinusT*t*p1 + 3f*OneMinusT*t*t*p2 + t*t*t*p3;
            }

 public static Vector3 GetFirstDerivative(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float t)
        {
            t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
            float oneMinusT = 1f - t;
            float it = oneMinusT;
            float it2 = oneMinusT*oneMinusT;
            float t2 = t*t;


            return (p0 * -it2 +
            p1 * (t * (3 * t - 4) + 1) +
            p2 * (-3 * t2 + t * 2) +
            p3* t2).normalized;

            return 3f*oneMinusT*oneMinusT*(p1 - p0) + 6f*oneMinusT*t*(p2 - p1) + 3f*t*t*(p3 - p2);
        }


        public static Vector3 GetSecondDerivative(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float t)
        {


            return (6*t*(p1 + 3*(p2 - p3) - p0) + 6*(p0 - 2*p2 + p3));
        }
```

I have no idea why, or how to fix  it. I have tried using a reference vector like Up to no avail, I even tried to negate the normal on certain conditions (Dot prouct of accel and tangent < -1).

Comment: My guess is that the normal is calculated by taking the cross product of the out of plane vector with the derivative along the Bezier curve.  You'll flip the direction of the splines are not defined in the same direction.  The first and third splines use points that progress from left to right; the second runs in the opposite direction.  Make all the points consistent and the normals will be in the same direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binormal can flip depending on the curvature of the curve. We are calculating
   B = T X dT
Consider an S-shaped curve in the plane. At the start of the curve these will in one orientation, giving an outward pointing bi-normal. At the end the they are in the opposite orientation giving inward pointing normal.

This fliped binormal will result in a flipped normal. A simple fix is just to use

```
normalOr = accel.normalise
```

A more advanced technique would be to impose continuity between successive vectors. So we calculate T1, N1, B1 at the first point, and T2, N1, B1. Now calculate T1 . T2, N1 . N2, B1 . B2. For continuous vector fields each of these dot products should be positive, if any are negative just flip the appropriate vector.

You always get problems around points with zero curvature and torsion.

Comment: using accel.normalise, does not seem to fix the issue, when extruding the a shape from that spline, I get these [artifacts](https://i1.someimage.com/mhMdJye.png).

Is there any other solution? Like adding a default direction for the normal? Or adding a Up Vector of the world and using that?

Comment: OK, so the sleepy idiot me just figured what you mean by the "more advanced technique" and that's exactly what I want ;) Thank you!